# Where to put custom-set-faces in the init.el in org-roam context?

Tags: faces, use-package, org-roam

I found a code snippet that can be used to have [different colors for links and org-roam links on SystemCrafters (aka David Wilson)](https://wiki.systemcrafters.cc/emacs/org-roam/#want-different-colors-for-org-roam-links-vs-other-links).

```
(custom-set-faces
  '((org-roam-link org-roam-link-current)
    :foreground "#e24888" :underline t))
```

But I am not sure where to put that into my `init.el`. I tried the `:config` section of the `use-package` directive:

```el
(use-package org-roam
      :init  ; is called before the package is loaded
      (setq org-roam-v2-ack t)  ; do not show migration warning after startup
      :custom
      (org-roam-directory "~/tab-cloud/my.org-roam")
      :bind (("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)
         ("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
         ("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert)
         )
      :config
      (require 'org-roam-dailies)
      (org-roam-db-autosync-mode)
      (custom-set-faces
       '((org-roam-link org-roam-link-current)
         :foreground "#e24888" :underline t))
      )
```

The error I receive is

```
  1 Error (use-package): org-roam/:config: Wrong type argument: symbolp,
  2 (org-roam-link org-roam-link-current)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should custom-set-face like this

```el
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-roam-link ((t (:foreground "#e24888" :underline t))))
 '(org-roam-link-current ((t (:foreground "#e24888" :underline t)))))
```

Also, you can leverage the use-package [`:custom-face`](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/keywords/#custom-face) keyword or `set-face-attribute`

However, there is not `org-roam-link` face in [org-roam v2](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/search?q=org-roam-link), you can find available faces by `M-x describe-face`.

Comment: But where in the `init.el` or in the `use-package` should I put that piece of code?

Comment: @buhtz anywhere you like it. As for `use-package`, after `:init` or use `:custom-face`

Comment: But your solution is for org-roam v1 only, correct?

Comment: @buhtz For how to customize the faces no. For these two faces I think yes, org roam v2 no longer has these two faces.